# css workflow with multipage website

Tags: html, css

I have created my first multipage website. now i was wondering how i should deal with the css workflow. creating one css file for everything? or a css file for every individual page? 
I am using a nav and a footer in every page.

Comment: The idea behind using a CSS file is to use the same styles on other pages as well, otherwise you can just embed your styles in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

If your project is not much complex then better to use one css file.
Specially in your case i suggest to use a single css file as you are going to use header and footer only the body container section will change for each page.